# Change the color of an element by holding the mouse over it and return its color by removing the mouse

Tags: javascript, html

By function `titlep(elem)`, placing the mouse on the numbers gives them a title and style. Now the problem is that when the mouse is removed from the numbers, the color of the numbers remains blue and does not return to the first state.
Someone friends can guide me.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  const number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  document.getElementById("in02").innerHTML = number
}, 5000);

function titlep(elem) {
  const aVal = document.getElementById('in02').textContent;
  const elemVal = elem.textContent.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
 elem.style="font-weight: bold;color: #0064ff;"
  elem.title = Number(aVal) * Number(elemVal);

}
```

```html
<div style="cursor: pointer">

  <span class="tp-cu-po" onmouseover="titlep(this)">4+  </span><br>
  <span class="tp-cu-po" onmouseover="titlep(this)">3+  </span><br>
  <span class="tp-cu-po" onmouseover="titlep(this)">2+  </span><br>
  <span class="tp-cu-po" onmouseover="titlep(this)">1+  </span><br>



</div><br> A =
<a id="in02"></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the colour change part, I suggest you use CSS, instead of JavaScript:

```
/* change the font-weight and color when a mouse hovers over the element */
.tp-cu-po:hover {
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #0064ff;
}

/* once the mouse leaves, element reverts back */
```

***EDIT***: if you don't want to use CSS, then perhaps you can try using `eventListeners`. Something like:

```
var requiredClass = document.getElementsByClassName("tp-cu-po");

// function for mouseover
function titlep(elem) {
  const aVal = document.getElementById('in02').textContent;
  const elemVal = elem.textContent.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  elem.style="font-weight: bold;color: #0064ff;"
  elem.title = Number(aVal) * Number(elemVal);
};

// function for mouseleave
function un_titlep(elem) {
  const aVal = document.getElementById('in02').textContent;
  const elemVal = elem.textContent.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  elem.style="font-weight: unser;color: black;" // set this to whatever you want it to be
  
}

for(var j = 0; j < requiredClass.length; j++){
    // when you mouse over
    requiredClass[j].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
        titlep(this);
    });
    // when you leave
    requiredClass[j].addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
        un_titlep(this);
    });
}
```

But of course, this requires more lines of code (and more possibility of error)

Comment: I do not want to use `css`

Answer (score 2):

```
<body>
  <p id="mypara" onmouseenter="changecolor(this)" onmouseleave="setnormal(this)"> 
    this is something new
   </p>
</body>

    <script>
     function changecolor(obj) {
       obj.style.color = "red";
     }

     function setnormal(obj) {
         obj.style.color = "black";
     }
</script>
```

Comment: edit description :- everything is same , but i just fixed one typos which somehow present there

Answer (score 1):

```js
setInterval(function () {
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    document.getElementById("in02").innerHTML = number;
}, 5000);

function titlep(elem) {
    const aVal = document.getElementById("in02").textContent;
    const elemVal = elem.textContent.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
    elem.style = "font-weight: bold;color: #0064ff;";
    elem.title = Number(aVal) * Number(elemVal);
}

// ADDED A SECOND FUNCTION THAT CHANGES THE COLOR BACK TO BLACK//

function titlep2(elem) {
    const aVal = document.getElementById("in02").textContent;
    const elemVal = elem.textContent.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
    elem.style = "color: black;";
    elem.title = Number(aVal) * Number(elemVal);
}
```

```html
<div style="cursor: pointer">

<!-- ADD A 'ONMOUSEOUT'-->

    <span class="tp-cu-po" onmouseover="titlep(this)" onmouseout="titlep2(this)">4+ </span><br>
    <span class="tp-cu-po" onmouseover="titlep(this)" onmouseout="titlep2(this)">3+ </span><br>
    <span class="tp-cu-po" onmouseover="titlep(this)" onmouseout="titlep2(this)">2+ </span><br>
    <span class="tp-cu-po" onmouseover="titlep(this)" onmouseout="titlep2(this)">1+ </span><br>

</div><br> A =
<a id="in02"></a>
```

Comment: or just use CSS and shorten the code.

.tp-cu-po:hover {
 color: blue;
 font-weight: 1000;
 font-style: bold;
}